VS Code not highlighting nested curly braces properly
The outside braces should be one color, and the inside braces another color. Instead, it's got both opening braces one color, and both closing another color. Anyone know how to fix this? The language here is JSX.

I've scoured the web, dug into my json file, and tried changing color themes, but no luck.

if it's a bug, it wouldn't be the first. https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/2748, https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/1575. if you raise a new issue ticket, please add the link to it here.
